Custom status of RMA - Magento 2.4.7
I am trying to add a custom status to Magento's default RMA functionality. I am currently working with Magento 2.4.7-p2 Enterprise Edition.
I have explored a few options, but there seem to be many possibilities and dependencies involved in this process.
Does anyone have any suggestions, references, or guidance on how to approach this effectively?
Thanks in advance...!!!
